# In a SConstruct, how do you get what 'scons --tree=all' would print out?

Tags: build, build-process, scons

[This stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7283452/determine-list-of-source-files-ch-for-a-complex-build-with-scons) shows how to get a list of all the dependencies for one or more targets.  How do you get the same thing from within a SConstruct file?

Edit:
That is, as an Object or something.  You could always recursively call scons -tree=all and grab stdout from that process, but I don't want a hack.  I'd like access to the dependency object scons is using.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to get this information is to just look at the source for SCons. You're looking for the file [SCons/Script/Main.py](http://scons.tigris.org/source/browse/scons/trunk/src/engine/SCons/Script/Main.py?view=markup), and in particular for the `TreePrinter` class. The basic idea is that all SCons nodes contain within themselves all the relevant details for reconstructing the dependancy graph.

The simplest test case I could think of is:

```
import os
env = Environment(ENV = os.environ)
app = env.Program('dummy', 'main.cpp')

for item in app:
    for child in item.all_children():
        print child
```

The code for doing this isn't really that complicated, but I certainly wouldn't want to rely on it not changing (it isn't part of the public interface for SCons).

Comment: Hmm, your example gives me a list of file dependencies, and those file dependencies do not contain any children.  Using SCons.Script.Main.TreePrinter().display(app) complains: 'NodeList' object has no attribute 'all_children'.  Your comment that "all SCons nodes contain within themselves..." is what I'm looking for.  I just don't know where that is documented so that I can figure out where to find the info and how to traverse the tree.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that is possible from within the code. The code in the SConstruct file is the code that generates the tree. So the tree cannot be provided before all the code in the SConstruct file is executed. On the other hand I think it should be possible to get the object you mention within python, if you have the patience to look through the Scons code to see how they operate their --tree option. But you will have to wait until the tree is generated before you access it.